# Authentication Error in Laravel 10 When Customizing Guard

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing an authentication error when customizing the guard. It's been 2 days and I haven't been able to fix it. I hope someone can help. Below is the source code:
auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'staff',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\StaffModel::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class StaffModel extends Authenticatable
{

    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'tbl_staff';
    protected $primaryKey = 'staff_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        "staff_name",
        "staff_birthday",
        "staff_gender",
        "staff_phone",
        "staff_email",
        "staff_password",
        "staff_address",
        "staff_position",
        "staff_role",
        "staff_status",
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'staff_password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function staff_login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'staff_email' => 'required|email',
            'staff_password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if (Auth::guard('staff')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Login successful.',
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid credentials.',
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $dataStaff = $request->all();

        // Mã hóa mật khẩu
        $hashedPassword = bcrypt($dataStaff['staff_password']);
        $dataStaff['staff_password'] = $hashedPassword;

        $staffModel = new StaffModel();
        $staffModel->fill($dataStaff);

        if ($staffModel->save()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Đã thêm nhân viên']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Thêm nhân viên thất bại']);
        }
    }
```

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Invalid credentials."
}
```

I'm sure I've entered the correct email and password, but the error keeps indicating login failure. I'm expecting some assistance, hoping to resolve this issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Attempt accepts `email` and `password` not `staff_email` or `staff_password`

Comment: Check the value of the `$credentials`

Comment: I have fixed it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the method `Auth::attempt` the password field must named **password** (in this exact case) because this method search for `password` field and hash it before checking it with database records, but in your case (password named `staff_password`) the `Auth::attempt` method doesn't know which field is the actual password field (so it doesn't know which one to hash), to solve this issue you have **two solutions**:

- Rename the `staff_password` column in the database to `password` **(not recommended)**.
- tell Laravel how to use your naming : **(Recommended)**

Add this code to your `StaffModel`.

##### App\Models\StaffModel.php :

```
...

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->staff_password;
}

...
```

By adding this method Laravel now know which column it has to be compared with a given password in the method `Auth::attempt`.

Now in the `AuthController` replace the `staff_login` method.

##### App\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php :

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function staff_login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'staff_email' => 'required|email',
            'staff_password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = [
            'staff_email' => $request->get('staff_email'),
            'password' => $request->get('staff_password'),
        ];

        if (Auth::guard('staff')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Login successful.',
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid credentials.',
            ]);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Summary

`Auth::attempt` methods checks an array of data with database records, and adds to that query the password checking query which hash then compare the array data with the key `password` with the data of the column that have the name getted from Model (it knows it using `getAuthPassword()`). something like `SELECT FROM users WHERE some_key= $credentials['some_key'] ... AND {getAuthPassword()} = Hashed($credentials['password'])`

Comment: I have fixed it, thank you very much.